# What is the correct way to declare a 'char' in an OpenAPI/Swagger-file?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

What is the correct way to declare a 'char' in an OpenAPI/Swagger-file? I tried these.. but didn't work

```
myTestProperty:
    type: char
    example: C or B
```

I tired this way as well, but no luck

```
myTestProperty:
    type: string
    format: char
    example: C or B
```

The documentation does specifically mention about the char data type and can't find elsewhere as well.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 5):

There is no `char` data type in OpenAPI. The closest approximation would be a `string` that has a `minLength` and `maxLength` of 1.

```
exampleProperty:
  type: string
  minLength: 1
  maxLength: 1
```